# populate response from a function in an object defined outside the function

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following code:

```
var obj = {};

function populateObject(){
   obj.firstname = `John`;
   obj.secondname = `Anderson`;
}

console.log(obj);
```

where I got an empty object while consoling obj. Is there a way where I can get values from inside the function to the object i.e., obj outside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't call the function.

```js
var obj = {};

function populateObject(){
   obj.firstname = `John`;
   obj.secondname = `Anderson`;
}
populateObject();
console.log(obj);
```

If you need a response from the function....

```js
function populateObject(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.firstname = `John`;
    obj.secondname = `Anderson`;
    return obj;
}
   
console.log( populateObject());
```